# Android support MediaRouter kills support design

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-cast-api

I am developing an app with Cast integration. I am able to set up a cast button and I'm even able to cast my app to ChromeCast. However, when I include `MediaRouter` as a dependency, I get a weird style (or absence of it) for the floating action button.

Here's the properly styled button:

[image: with proper styling]

And here's what happens when I add the `MediaRouter` dependency:

[image: without style]

```
// build.gradle
dependencies {
    // ....

    // Removing the mediarouter fixes the "design" of the toaster, but then crashes app
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    // ...
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this or on how should I address it?

Comment: Have you tried to set the castBackground to @drawable/abc_dialog_material_background

Comment: may you post the code how you styling button

Comment: That looks like a dialog to me, not a Button.

Comment: You mentioned you get a crash if you remove medirouter-v7. Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @EugenPechanec the crash is basically because the callbacks for the MediaRouter are not defined when you don't include its library.

Comment: Just post it so I know exactly. Also post the code that triggers the dialog. I'll look into it.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I've basically been following the manual here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate . You can find the basic code here: https://pastebin.com/QXcc2sFc and the stacktrace when I don't include the lib here: https://pastebin.com/zJr7aaAt

Comment: @NizaSiwale Even though I didn't want to customize the style, that goes in line with the other answer and it's the only work-around I seem to find so far.

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves Hey, Can you share a little bit of code or link How can I integrate cast to my existing android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case you can also add a [custom style](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_advanced#customize-theme-introductory-overlay) and then try to copy the [Material Design style](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/).